# how to find the co-ordinates(lati&long) of a selected location in objective c

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, autocomplete

I am using Google Autocomplete API and i am getting the place name and placeid but I am unable to get the co-rdinate of the place.
Sir, how can i find the co-ordinate.

```
 GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity;

    [_placesClient autocompleteQuery:@"s"//this should be your textfield text
                              bounds:nil
                              filter:filter
                            callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                                if (error != nil) {
                                    NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                    return;
                                }

                                for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {


                                    NSDictionary *aTempDict =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:result.attributedFullText.string,@"description",result.placeID,@"reference", nil];
                                    PlaceObject *placeObj=[[PlaceObject alloc]initWithPlaceName:[aTempDict objectForKey:@"description"]];
                                    placeObj.userInfo=aTempDict;
                                    //                                    [finalarray addObject:placeObj];
                                    NSLog(@"Result '%@' with placeID %@", result.attributedFullText.string, result.placeID);
                                    NSLog(@"%@",finalarray);
                                    [finalarray addObject:result.attributedFullText.string];
                                    NSString *aStrPlaceReferance=[placeObj.userInfo objectForKey:@"reference"];

                                          NSLog(@"%@",aStrPlaceReferance);

                                    NSString *aStrPlaceReferance1=[placeObj.userInfo objectForKey:@"description"];

                                    NSLog(@"%@",aStrPlaceReferance1);


                                }



                            }];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never used this API but from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_prediction.html#property-documentation) it looks like you should use the `placeID` property of each `GMSAutocompletePrediction` object and make a new request to get the information you need.

According to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details), you need to call `GMSPlacesClient lookUpPlaceID:callback:` like that:

```
// A hotel in Saigon with an attribution.
NSString *placeID = @"ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs";

[_placesClient lookUpPlaceID:placeID callback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
  if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Place Details error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
  }

  if (place != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
    NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
    NSLog(@"Place placeID %@", place.placeID);
    NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"No place details for %@", placeID);
  }
}];
```

and then use the `place.coordinate` property.